# How to create load balancer on New Azure Portal in resource manager mode.

Tags: azure-resource-manager

There no "add" button when I browse load balancers, is that means we can only create load balancer in resource manager mode with PowerShell or CLI Only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A LB in AzureRM requires a Virtual Network.

A simple way to create that, though while not as nice as the overall portal experience, does not require CLI/PowerShell/REST.

https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/tree/master/101-create-internal-loadbalancer

Has a button on the page to "Deploy to Azure".

Comment: This is the easiest way for users to create LB currently. Hope this feature will be added to New Portal soon.

Answer (score 1):

Besides PowerShell or CLI, you can also create Load Balancer in Resource Manager mode with **Azure Resource Manager REST API** for Load Balancers CRUD operations.

Refer to this link 
[Load Balancer ARM REST APIs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt163651.aspx)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Yes, REST API is another way to create LB, but not all customers can do this, most of customers use Web Console for their work. If there is no way to create LB in Resource Manager mode with Azure New Portal, I think this is retrogression, after all, create LB in Classic mode is easy on pervious Azure Portal.